# Quiero sumar los renglones y nose cual es el error, Codigo c

Tags: c, codeblocks

Hola soy nuevo en esto, quería hacer un array donde me de el resultado del primer, segundo, tercero
y cuarto renglón

```
int ren=4;
int col=6;
int matriz[ren][col];
int sumatotal=0;

 for(int renglon=0;renglon<ren;renglon++){
 for(int columna=0;columna<col;columna++){

 matriz[ren][col]=10+rand()%51;

  printf(" %d ",matriz[ren][col]);
 }

 }

Hasta aca voy bien, pero despues cuando quiero sumar me da cualquier resultado

for(int renglon=0;renglon<ren;renglon++){

    printf("la suma del renglon %d",renglon);

 for(int columna=0;columna<col;columna++){


 sumatotal=sumatotal+matriz[ren][col];
 }

 printf("\n  ---> %d \n",sumatotal);
```

por los ejemplos similares que vi, esta bien estructurado

Answer (score 0):

El principal problema que he visto es que dentro del for la matriz a la que das valor siempre es la misma porque ren y col no cambian de numero los que cambian son los valores de renglon y columna. En el siguiente programa yo he iniciado estas dos variables antes y no dentro del for porque me daba problemas, pero no se si se puede hacerse de tu manera.

```
int renglon,columna;
int ren=4;
int col=6;
int matriz[ren][col];
int sumatotal=0;
for(renglon=0;renglon<ren;renglon++)
{
    for(columna=0;columna<col;columna++)
    {
        matriz[renglon][columna]=10+rand()%51;
        printf(" %d ",matriz[renglon][columna]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

for(renglon=0;renglon<ren;renglon++)
{
    sumatotal=0;
    printf("la suma del renglon %d",renglon);
    for(columna=0;columna<col;columna++)
    {
        sumatotal=sumatotal+matriz[renglon][columna];
    }
     printf("\n  ---> %d \n",sumatotal);
}
```